Reset Password not connecting to Firebase authentication
I developed a project on android studio. created UI for login, forgot password. The login is connecting very well with FIREBASE but when I click on forgot password button after inputting email, it crashes and returns to login UI. Below are my Java class for forgot password.
public class ForgetPassword extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText emailEditText;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private Button resetPassword;
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
String Email;
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_forget_password);

            emailEditText = findViewById(R.id.inputEmail);
            Button resetPasswordButton = findViewById(R.id.resetPassword);
            progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

            resetPasswordButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            String email = emailEditText.getText().toString().trim();
            if (email.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(ForgetPassword.this, "Please enter a registered email",             
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            emailEditText.setError("Email is Required");
            emailEditText.requestFocus();
            } else if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
            emailEditText.setError("Valid email is Required");
                    emailEditText.requestFocus();
                    } else {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    resetPassword();

                    }
                });

                }

                private void resetPassword() {
                FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                mAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(Email).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(ForgetPassword.this, "Please check inbox for reset  
                            passwordlink!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    new Intent(ForgetPassword.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    //Clear stack to prevent user coming back to ForgotPassword
                    startActivity(null);
                    finish();
                    }else {
                    Toast.makeText(ForgetPassword.this, "Something went wrong!!", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                });
                }
            }

I rebuilt the project but yet, It does crash and returns back to login page. Where did I go wrong?
